# MYSQL Geometric mean calc not working with CURRENT_DATE()

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate a geometric mean of today's available records. The query below works fine when I do not include CURRENT_DATE(), but that is essential to get just today's records.

```
SELECT id,EXP( SUM( LOG( atmosphere ) ) / COUNT( atmosphere ) ) AS atmosphere,
       EXP( SUM( LOG( gender ) ) / COUNT( gender) ) AS gender,
       EXP( SUM( LOG( wait ) ) / COUNT( wait ) ) AS wait
FROM ratings
WHERE location_id = $id AND upload_time= CURRENT_DATE()
```

upload_time is set as DATETIME in the MYSQL table.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: How does it not work?  What is the version that does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT id,EXP( SUM( LOG( atmosphere ) ) / COUNT( atmosphere ) ) AS atmosphere,EXP( SUM( LOG( gender ) ) / COUNT( gender) ) AS gender,EXP( SUM( LOG( wait ) ) / COUNT( wait ) ) AS wait FROM ratings WHERE location_id = $id AND DATE(upload_time) = CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: I think Date(upload_time) did the trick, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @ZRD Because otherwise you're comparing the date and time, not just the date. `CURRENT_DATE()` will only match if the time in the table column is `00:00:00`.

Comment: oh, I knew it was something obvious, I missed, thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: It's because your upload_time is in Datetime format. And it should only compare date without the time. Like: 2014-08-21 is not equal to 2014-08-21 08:00:00 :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract the date from your datetime field, `upload_time` since it'll be comparing `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` with `yyyy-mm-dd`

use mysql's `DATE()` function for that - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

you'll end up with this in your where statement

```
DATE(upload_time) = CURRENT_DATE()
```